# python: how to print huge records page by page

Tags: python, printing

```
def test():
        for x in get_data_group(DATA):
            print x
```

there are aound 2000 records in get_data_group
I don't want to print these in the screen via cli in one time

any good idea to make it better?

Comment: Will something like `python file.py | less` work in this case?

Comment: For which definition of "better" ???

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in get_data_group(DATA)[:10]:
```

Or, maybe the following would suit you better:

```
def test():
    for x in range(2000):
        yield x

g = test()

for i in range(10):
    print(next(g))

print('-' * 20)

for i in range(10):
    print(next(g))

--output:--
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
--------------------
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pager` from the [pydoc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pydoc.html) module:

```
from pydoc import pager

def test():
    for x in get_data_group(DATA):
        pager(x)
```

Comment: actually get_data_group(DATA) is a list with more than 2000 records                         . I want to print 100 records per page,and when they press 'space' ,the screen will show them the next 100 records.

Comment: `pager()` will show as many records as will fit on one screen, based on the window size calculation (not necessarily 100 records). When you hit space, it shows the next set of records.

Comment: it only shows one record per pager and I hit ''q" to see the next record.                                                                                                                   
23.20.234.231
(END)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `pprint` (pretty printer) module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html):

```
import pprint

def test():
    data = get_data_group(DATA):
    pretty_printer = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=1, width=80, depth=2)
    pretty_printer.pprint(data)
```

You can customize the parameters `indent` and `width`. If your data structure has nested data inside, you can use the `depth` parameter on `PrettyPrinter`'s constructor.

Comment: Indenting/wrapping and paging are orthogonal concepts.

Comment: actually get_data_group(DATA) is a list with more than 2000 records . I want to print 100 records per page,and when they press 'space' ,the screen will show them the next 100 records